# Email notification for Account ownership change is not being sent for some types of Accounts

Tags: account, ownership, owner

When changing Account owner and ticking "Send Notification Email" checkbox, new owner should receive notification via email:

[image]
We have configured three Record Types for Account object. Automatic notifications works well for two Record Types but not for the third one. Somehow the problem is related to Record Types. What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: No, nothing. The pop up closed as usual.